# How to resize images within card groups using bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Good evening all!

I've written the following code which was working perfectly. But using the images I use which are different resolutions this makes the card images different sizes. Is there a way to make all the images scale to the same size?

Example here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1mtb.jpg

My code is using Bootstrap 4 CDN.

```
<section>
          <div class="container">
          <div class="card-group">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="assets/images/removals.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="assets/images/truck image.png" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="assets/images/sprintervan.png" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Any help would be amazing!

Thank you.

Comment: This is not code its markup language and go learn some basic css, changing bootstrap won't help you if you dont even know basic css

Answer (score 1):

From your example, it looks like you're having a problem with height.

> Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with .img-fluid. max-width: 100%; and height: auto; are applied to the image so that it scales with the parent element.
>
> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/

A suggested workaround would be to add **.h-100** (height 100%) to the parent node of each fluid img card

```
<div class="h-100">
    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="assets/images/removals.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
</div>
```

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21885